# Where is the value in HEX for the file size in a jpg (exif)

Tags: hex, jpeg, exif, recovery, carve

I can carve out images no problem, but I remember a long time ago being shown where to find the file length of a jpg (in bytes) so that if i had issue with an auto recovery i can do it manually.

where in a jpg exif header in HEX are the values (which i know needs converting into little endian?) that tell me the size of the file, so i can scroll to the end of the file, find FF d9 and recover the image.

Can anyone point me to where those HEX values are in these types of JPG's?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would a file contain its own size? Ask the filesystem!

Comment: BTW EOI (FFD9) may not be at the end of the file. In particular some Samsung phones produce JPEGs with proprietary trailing data. You should parse the file's segments from top to bottom.